# postgresql order by desc for string not working

Tags: java, postgresql

Using postgresql on a mac, I'm trying to order names in descending but I have noticed if the two names have the same first letter it does not check the second letter when trying to order.

For example suppose you have the following strings:

```
Amen, Alia, Atis,...etc
```

They should ideally be order as:

```
Alia, Amen, Atis,..etc
```

But postgresql only checks the first letter and doesn't seem to check the entire string. Therefore the order of names returned by postgresql is:

```
Atis, Alia, Amen,..etc
```

or in just some random order. I have set the database collation to en_us.utf8.

The simplified query I'm trying to use is:

```
SELECT name 
FROM properties 
ORDER BY name;
```

How can I make postgresql order by the entire string, is that possible?

Update:
When I try the query in pgadmin III, I find that it produces the same results, I think it may have something to do with the configuration of postgreSQL.

My configs of db are:
collation and character type are: en_CA.UTF-8 
tablespace: pg_default

Is there something wrong with the configuration I have set up on a mac?

Comment: @klin the query is: SELECT name FROM properties LEFT OUTER JOIN observations on (properties.id =observations.id) order by name desc

Comment: Postgres surely does order by all letters (entire column content). Did you check for capital letters? "AZ" comes first than "Aa". Also, add your query to the question.

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida all the names are converted to lower case before applying the query, but the same query works on a windows but doesn't seem to work on a mac. I'm not sure if it has to do something with the version of postgresql or the collation.

Comment: It is probably an issue of collation. To determine if so, try `SELECT name FROM properties ORDER BY name COLLATE "C"`

Comment: @klin I have tried the query you suggested but it still contains incorrect ordering like for descending or ascending it places "test" before "the sheet metal". I don't know which collation to choose from?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are experiencing issues with collation and/or non-printable characters.

You can try different collations as per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html with:

```
SELECT name COLLATE "C", name::bytea FROM properties 
LEFT OUTER JOIN observations on properties.id =observations.id order by 1 desc;
```

and you will be able to both experiment with collation (1st col) and see what exactly (hex binary value) is stored in `name` (2nd col).

**Edit:** After finding [this Postgres.app issue](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/216#issuecomment-58474023), I'm fairly confident you've hit a bug in OSX collation support. To confirm, you can try sorting the same text in console using `sort`.

I don't know if a workaround exists at this moment, but the [PGDG is aware of the problem](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:ICU) and if all goes well, [PostgreSQL 9.6 might solve your problem](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/553556E8.6030702@gmx.net).

Comment: I have tried the query you suggested but it still contains incorrect ordering like for descending or ascending it places "test" before "the sheet metal". I don't know which collation to choose from?

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, this happens on OSX. How did you install PostgreSQL? http://postgresapp.com/ ? Can you try another way or another version?


Also -- this might be helpful: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/216#issuecomment-58474023

Answer (score 0):

`Natural order sort` it's what You looking for.

### PSQL functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION btrsort_nextunit(text) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 ~ '[^0-9]+' THEN
COALESCE( SUBSTR( $1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '[^0-9]+'))+1 ),
'' )
ELSE
COALESCE( SUBSTR( $1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '[0-9]+'))+1 ),
'' )
END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE FUNCTION btrsort(text, integer) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN $2-1&gt;0
THEN
RPAD(SUBSTR(COALESCE(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '^[^0-9]+'), ''), 1, 12), 12, ' ') ||
LPAD(SUBSTR(COALESCE(SUBSTRING(btrsort_nextunit($1) FROM '^[0-9]+'), ''), 1, 12), 12, 0) || btrsort(btrsort_nextunit(btrsort_nextunit($1)), $2-1)
ELSE
RPAD(SUBSTR(COALESCE(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '^[^0-9]+'), ''), 1, 12), 12, ' ') ||
LPAD(SUBSTR(COALESCE(SUBSTRING(btrsort_nextunit($1) FROM '^[0-9]+'), ''), 1, 12), 12, 0)
END
;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE FUNCTION btrsort(text) RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT btrsort($1, 10);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

### Usage

```
SELECT room_number
FROM (SELECT room_number, btrsort(room_number) AS room_sort
FROM rooms
ORDER BY room_sort) AS foo
```

### Result

```
room_number
-----------
8
9
9a
10
```

### Links

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/queries-order.html
http://2kan.tumblr.com/post/361326656/postgres-natural-ordering